# “GPG error: https://oss.oracle.com/debian unstable Release”

Tags: debian, apt, update

The error I am having when trying to update my package list.

```
root@wetainfotech:/# apt update
Hit:1 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 https://packages.sury.org/php buster InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease
Ign:6 https://oss.oracle.com/debian unstable InRelease
Get:8 https://oss.oracle.com/debian unstable Release [2,126 B]
Get:9 https://oss.oracle.com/debian unstable Release.gpg [189 B]
Ign:9 https://oss.oracle.com/debian unstable Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://oss.oracle.com/debian unstable Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 2E2BCDBCB38A8516 Oracle OSS group (Open Source Software group) <build@oss.oracle.com> 1122A29AB257825F322C234E2E2BCDBCB38A8516
E: The repository 'http://oss.oracle.com/debian unstable Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try with this Oneliner

```sh
sudo apt-key list  | grep "expired: " | sed -ne 's|pub .*/\([^ ]*\) .*|\1|gp' | xargs -n1 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys
```

It were foundable by using google, however one Duplicate also on [Ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650032/gpg-errorthe-following-signatures-were-invalid-keyexpired)